# How to remove None from the result of a function?

Tags: python, nonetype, topic-modeling, nmf

I'm sorry, but I still can not solve this None problem. I am using an NMF algorithm to have the themes of a corpus and then I try to retrieve the documents attached to each topic. But None prevents me! When I try to retrieve the documents, I have an error

Script:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

def display_topics(model, feature_names, n_top_words):
    for topic_idx, topic in enumerate(model.components_):
        print "Topic %d:" % (topic_idx)
        print " ".join([feature_names[i] for i in topic.argsort()[:-n_top_words - 1:-1]])  

text = pandas.read_csv('pretraitement_virgile.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
good_text = text['phrase']
bad_text = text['raw_phrase']
bad_text_list = bad_text.values.tolist()
good_text_list = good_text.values.tolist()

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(good_text_list)
tfidf_feature_names = tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

topics_number = 3

# Run NMF
nmf = NMF(n_components=topics_number, random_state=1, alpha=.1, l1_ratio=.5, init='nndsvd').fit(tfidf)
document_topics = nmf.fit_transform(tfidf)

n_top_words = 10
print 'NMF topics'
topics = display_topics(nmf, tfidf_feature_names, n_top_words)
print topics

print 

print 'Documents per topic'
for topic in range(len(topics)): 
    if topic == None:
        pass
    else:
        print("Topic {}:".format(topic))
        docs = np.argsort(document_topics[:, topic])[::-1]
        for mail in docs[:3]:
            bad_text_list_n = " ".join(bad_text_list[mail].split(",")[:2])
            print (" ".join(good_text_list[mail].split(",")[:2]) + ',' + bad_text_list_n)
```

I tried to put a condition to ignore the Name, but it does not work.I still have the same error.

> Topic 0:
>
> order cancel delivery date not want store always well ahead
>
> Topic 1:
>
> product not broken only package arrived received color color delivered
>
> Topic 2:
>
> product not return site store receipt order available in advance
>
> None
>
> Documents par topic
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "NMF.py", line 49, in 
>       for topic in range(len(topics)):
>
> TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

I need this result:

> Topic 0:
>
> order cancel delivery date not want store always well ahead
>
> Topic 1:
>
> product not broken only package arrived received color color delivered
>
> Topic 2:
>
> product not return site store receipt order available in advance
>
> Documents par topic
>
> Topic 0:
>
> text text text
>
> text text text
>
> text text text
>
> Topic 1:
>
> text text text
>
> text text text
>
> text text text
>
> Topic 2:
>
> text text text
>
> text text text
>
> text text text

**Some (stupid) data exemple:**

```
phrase,raw_phrase
delicious fruit mango, the mango is a delicious fruit
important object computer, the computer is an important object
popular banana fruit, banana is a popular fruit
pen important thing, pen is an important thing
purple grape, the grape is purple
phone world object, the phone is a worldwide object
```

Comment: maybe just try `for topic in topics:` instead of `for topic in range(len(topics))`

Comment: Could you also paste some sample data to recreate the error?

Comment: @amanbirs Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the error message your error happens in this line:

```
for topic in range(len(topics)):
```

because python tries to get the length of the object `topics`, being a `None` Type it has no length.

If you want to skip the whole loop when `topics` is `Null` you can use:

```
for topic in topics:
```

and change all `topics[topic]` to just `topic`

Or if you want to catch that error you can write:

```
try:
    l = len(topics)
except TypeError:
    # do somthing about it like:
    l = 0

for topic in range(l):
   # go on in topic loop
```

Or you can check for the None after the creation of the `topics` object with:

```
if variable is None:
    topics = #something else or empty with ""
```

Answer (score 4):

Your procedure `display_topics` doesn't return anything, yet you assign the result of it to the variable `topics`, which is then set to `Null`. And you can't iterate over a `Null` object.

Comment: thanks but I just need to remove this None so that all the script works...

Comment: @marin Well, what should be the value of `topics`? What is it, you want to iterate over?

Comment: I want to retrieve the documents attached to each topic. If I do this: print 'Topic 0' docs = np.argsort (document_topics [:, 0]) [:: - 1]
it works but if I try to retrieve all topics and documents, it doesn't work...

Comment: Then you need to **return** those things from `display_topics`.